# WACOM Bamboo FUN Pen&Touch

Tags: 12.10, wacom

I’m using a 12.10 with Gnome desktop for now and just started to learn couple of things about it. I have a Lenovo i5 with a nVidia GeForce GT635M but because of numerous issues I use the default Nouveau driver for it.

I'm planning on buying a new graphic tablet, I haven’t used one yet. I’m considering a WACOM Bamboo FUN Pen&Touch Small . I’m not a professional and I won’t need something very expensive in the first place and this seems like a good choice. My only experience with drawing until now was been pen and paper.

Did a short search on the forum and found couple of tips and advises about installing this thing. I guess I’ll try those when I’ll have the tablet in my hands. 
I just have a couple of questions before buying it:

For people who are using it with Ubuntu, would you recommend something else in this price range?. From my little google research there are pretty good reviews for this model but I’m open to suggestions.

Does anyone have a complete set of instructions for installing it(meaning something that will help me use all its features?

What app do you use for it, I have two or three apps that came with gnome but if there is something better you recommend I would like to hear about it?

I’m not a native English speaker so if there is something unclear or misspelled in my message I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I have already tried 2 wacom models and just yesterday a student who I am teaching Ubuntu to brought a Wacom tablet, the Bamboo Create one. For 12.10 and 13.04 (The ones I tested yesterday for the class) you can simply connect the device and it will work out of the box.

If you need to configure anything for it (Like sensibility, orientation...) you will need to go to the System Settings panel and select **Wacom Tablet**.

[image]

It should give you all options available for that particular tablet.

For programs that work with it, well we tested yesterday Gimp, Inkscape and even the Compiz Fire effect. It could also be used as a touchscreen to select items in the Desktop.